# ContextError: useModalStyles returned is 'undefined'. Seems you forgot to wrap the components in "<Modal />"

Tags: unit-testing, next.js13, chakra-ui

this is jest unit test

ContextError: useModalStyles returned is 'undefined'. Seems you forgot to wrap the components in ""

```
jest.mock('@chakra-ui/react', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('@chakra-ui/react');

  return {
    ...originalModule,
    useModalStyles: jest.fn(() => ({}))
  };
});

describe('AppPage Component', () => {
  const eventId = 'your-event-id';
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const mockCalendarEventQueryData = {
      data: {
        calendarEvent: {
          title: 'Mocked Event Title',
          children: [],
          members: []
        }
      }
    };
    (useCalendarEventQuery as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => ({
      ...mockCalendarEventQueryData
    }));

    // Mocking the useUpdateSessionMutation hook

    render(<EditEvent eventId={eventId} />);
  });
});
```

this is component

give me some suggestion to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

You might have to wrap your tests in the `ChakraProvider` like was done for the app. This is part of their "Getting Started" [documentation](https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/cra-guide#2-provider-setup) but also needs to be done in tests.

The `useModalStyles` hook (and other components that may be in the React tree) probably relies on information from that context to function.

```
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'; // import 

jest.mock('@chakra-ui/react', () => {
    // ...you can keep the mock, but may not need it if
    // it functions correctly with the provider
});

describe('EditEvent Component', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    render(
      <ChakraProvider>
        <EditEvent eventId="your-event-id" />
      </ChakraProvider>
    );

    // ...continue test here
  });
});
```

Comment: same error is coming after added  => ContextError: useModalStyles returned is 'undefined'. Seems you forgot to wrap the components in "<Modal />"


      61 |
    > 62 |     render(
         |           ^
      63 |       <ChakraProvider>
      64 |         <EditEvent eventId="your-event-id" />
      65 |       </ChakraProvider>